# Dropdown Category Menu for Fastest Magento 2 Theme

Tags: themes, magento2

I have just installed the Fastest Magento 2 Theme.  The options for displaying the menu that I found are the Catalog Category Tree widget which looks like this

[image]

I would like to use a dropdown menu because the above is too long.

When I went to Content > Pages and selected edit on the Home Page and then chose the Insert Widget option I saw this list of options.

CMS Page Link,
CMS Static Block,
Catalog Category Link,
Catalog New Products List,
Catalog Product Link,
Catalog Products List,
Catalog AMP Products List,
Catalog Brand List,
Catalog Category Tree,
Catalog Contact Form,
Catalog Featured Looks List,
Catalog Google Map,
Catalog Instagram Recent Photos,
Catalog Megamenu,
Catalog Product Filter,
Catalog Slideshow,
Magefan Blog Extension - Blog Author Link,
Magefan Blog Extension - Blog Category Link,
Magefan Blog Extension - Blog Post Link,
Magefan Blog Extension - Blog Tage Link,
Magefan Blog Extension - Featured Blog Posts,
Magefan Blog Extension - Recent Blog Posts,
Magefan Blog Posts List,
Orders and Returns,
Recently Compared Products,
Recently Viewed Products,

I tried selecting Catalog Megamenu shown in the picture below, but the dropdown selection is empty and it looks like the Megamenu has to be created somewhere on the backend before it can be used to a page.  I am wondering if the Megamenu is the right way to create a dropdown menu, and if it is how to create one.  Otherwise I am wondering how you can create a dropdown menu, either in the Magento 2 interface or programmatically.

[image: Catalog Megamenu Widget]